can i skip the expresson of <T> when it is not nessrly defined?
is there any syntax to avoid writing <T> notation in the statement when the coder don't use that at all?
what i want looks like:
interface Props<?T> {
  className: string
  data?: T
}

const props: Props = {className: "hello, world"}
const propswithdata: Props<T> = {className: "hw", data: {something: "something"}}


I think you could use Pick<T> here
interface Props<T> {
  className: string
  data?: T
}

type PropsWithoutData = Pick<Props<never>, 'className'>;

Playground link
Since Props is generic without any default type for T, you have at least specify something. If you can modify Props<T>, you could specify a default for it
interface Props<T = never> {
  className: string
  data?: T
}


i just decided to use < never > for the case i dont use data
